# Calculate useAll field

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the input table, I hope to set a field for `FreightTypeID` called `useAll`

`useAll` is 1 if there does not exist a nil value,

otherwise, it's 0.

This is the input table

```
   FreightID  FreightTypeID  Order
0          1              1    1.0
1          2              1    3.0
2          3              1    NaN
3          4              2    1.0
4          5              2    2.0
5          6              2    3.0
6          7              3    NaN
7          8              3    NaN
8          9              3    NaN
```

And the code for input table:

```
solution_dic = {"FreightID": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], "FreightTypeID": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], "Order": [1,3,None,1,2,3,None,None,None]}
df=pd.DataFrame(solution_dic)
```

Below is the outcome

```
   FreightTypeID  UseAll
0              1       0
1              2       1
2              3       0
```

How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.groupby('FreightTypeID')['Order'].apply(lambda x: ~x.isnull().values.any())
```

Or:

```
df.groupby('FreightTypeID')['Order'].apply(lambda x: x.notna().all())
```

Output:

```
FreightTypeID
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Order, dtype: bool
```

Changing to what you want:

```
df.groupby('FreightTypeID')['Order'].apply(lambda x: x.notna().all().astype(int)).reset_index(name='UseAll')
```

Which produces:

```
FreightTypeID   UseAll
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   0
```